# Implement Python 3's round function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, google-app-engine, rounding

I am using some old codes written in Python 3 in my Google-App-Engine project which is using Python 2.7. The different round() algorithms in Python 3 and Python 2 gives me a headache. Is there any convenient way to implement a Python 3's round() method in Python 2.7?

A further question: Python 2 and Python 3 handle the integer operations quite differently. For example the following statements have different outputs in Python 2 and 3:

```
2/4   # 0 in Python 2, 0.5 in Python 3
round(3/2)  
math.ceil(0.5)   # 1.0 in Python 2, 1 in Python 3
```

Any easy way to convert codes from Python 3 to Python 2 while keeping the behavior to be exactly the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `from __future__ import division` to get py3.x's division behaviour in py2.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Banker's rounding is implemented in [future](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/future/). Float division can be made the default with a `__future__` import.

```
from __future__ import division
from future.modified_builtins import round
```

Comment: I tried "from future.modified_builtins import round" in my Python 2.7, and got ImportError says: No module named future.modified_builtins. I cannot get useful results about this "future.modified_builtins" library. Anything wrong here?

Comment: Did you try installing it first?

Comment: I didn't specifically install it. Only standard Python 2.7 and GAE libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I got it here: https://github.com/edschofield/python-future/blob/master/future/modified_builtins/newround.py  I've thought it included in the standard 2.7 distribution.

Comment: @TaoChen The link is no longer valid

Comment: What needs to be installed for this? Even after `sudo pip install future` it doesn't work

Comment: @DakshShah: `__future__` is part of the stdlib.